# Add Popuop menu tool in CAB Main Menu Extention site

Tags: infragistics, cab

I am developing  application using CAB and i am using Infragistics CAB Extensibility kit.

I am facing one problem. i am unable to create Popup menu tool in Main menu. It shows me only Popup menu tool text and image and does not show Child button tools.  here is my code to register in Main Menu

```
PopupMenuTool zoomButton = new PopupMenuTool("Zoom");
            zoomButton.SharedProps.AppearancesSmall.Appearance.Image = Properties.Resources.bmw_m32;
            zoomButton.SharedProps.DisplayStyle = ToolDisplayStyle.ImageAndText;
            zoomButton.SharedProps.Caption = "Zoom";

            zoomButton.DropDownArrowStyle = DropDownArrowStyle.Segmented;
            // Specifies the Popup Style as Menu
            zoomButton.Settings.PopupStyle = PopupStyle.Menu;


            var zoom1X = new ButtonTool("GZoom1");
            zoom1X.SharedProps.DisplayStyle = ToolDisplayStyle.TextOnlyAlways;
            zoom1X.SharedProps.Caption = "Lavel 1";


            zoomButton.Tools.Add(zoom1X);

            WorkItem.UIExtensionSites[Constants.UIExtensionSiteNames.MainMenu].Add(zoomButton)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from BankTeller sample provided by infragistics.

First i have to Register PopupMenuTool.Tools collection to my UIExtentionSite and then have to add ButtonTools in this collection..

Code should be like this

```
PopupMenuTool zoomButton = new PopupMenuTool("Zoom");
            zoomButton.SharedProps.AppearancesSmall.Appearance.Image = Properties.Resources.bmw_m32;
            zoomButton.SharedProps.DisplayStyle = ToolDisplayStyle.ImageAndText;


            // Specifies the Popup Style as Menu
            zoomButton.Settings.PopupStyle = PopupStyle.Menu;
            zoomButton.DropDownArrowStyle = DropDownArrowStyle.Segmented;
            WorkItem.UIExtensionSites[Constants.UIExtensionSiteNames.MainToolbar].Add(zoomButton);

            WorkItem.UIExtensionSites.RegisterSite("ZoomTools", zoomButton.Tools);

            ButtonTool zoom1X = new ButtonTool("Zoom 1 X");
            zoom1X.SharedProps.Caption = "Level 1";
            WorkItem.UIExtensionSites["ZoomTools"].Add(zoom1X);
```